# Add page number to hyperlinks in a Word document

Tags: google-docs

I have a large number of documents created using Google Docs which contain hyperlinks to section headings.  This works fine when viewed online, or exported to Word/PDF and viewed electronically, but they're obviously useless in print.  What's the best way to get a page number (preferably) or section number (would do in a pinch) into the displayed text of the hyperlinks?  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please see [how-do-I-ask-a-good-question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and show what you have tried for us to help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a workable, though not particularly elegant, solution.  It does not automatically update, so you only run it once before printing.  Putting here in case it helps other people like me :)

```
Sub AddPageNumberToHyperlink()
    For Each link In ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks
        ' Find target heading and get its text
        link.Follow
        ' Get current pagenumber (since we just followed the link) and add to display text
        link.TextToDisplay = link.TextToDisplay + " on page " + Str(Selection.Range.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber))
    Next
End Sub
```